# Move empty factor levels while maintaining order of non-empty levels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a ggplot2 column plot using calculated values by factor level. I wish to create a plot where the empty factor levels are shown on the plot, but kept at the bottom of the axis. Right now, they are at the top. I have reordered my factors based on calculated value and want to maintain that for them. I will include sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl),
    cyl = fct_expand(cyl, c("2", "4", "6", "8"))) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(meanMPG = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cyl = fct_reorder(cyl, meanMPG)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = meanMPG)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() # shows empty level "2" on the top
```

[image: empty levels on top of axis]

Comment: So you want the graph to be in order 4, 6, 8 and then 2 (because it's empty)?

Comment: @dash2 Yes! Exactly. I should mention my actual dataframe is programmed in a function, so I need to do this without knowing ahead of time which factor levels are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was surprisingly tricky - given that all you need to do is order your levels correctly. I couldn't find anything in `forcats` that was directly appropriate, but we can write our own reordering function.

```r
my_reorder <- function (fac, var) {
  fac <- fct_reorder(fac, {{var}})
  l <- levels(fac)
  nonempty <- levels(factor(fac)) # I got this idea from droplevels()
  empty <- setdiff(l, nonempty)
  fct_relevel(fac, empty, nonempty)
  fct_relevel(fac, empty, nonempty)
}

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl),
         cyl = fct_expand(cyl, c("2", "4", "6", "8"))) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(meanMPG = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cyl = my_reorder(cyl, meanMPG)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = meanMPG)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE, ) +
  coord_flip() # shows empty level "2" on the top
```

Comment: this is a blessing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `.drop = FALSE` in `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl = fct_expand(as.factor(cyl), c('2', '4', '6', '8')), 
     .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarize(meanMPG = mean(mpg), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  arrange(!is.na(meanMPG), meanMPG) %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = cyl)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = meanMPG)) +
    geom_col() + 
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    coord_flip()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: this is good for dropping the level "2" but I want to keep it and just move it to the end on the axis